# How to Get the Value of a Checkbox in Razor

Tags: c#, razor

I have a form containing the following:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="a1" >
```

In my Razor/C# code I want to assign to an integer `var a1` the value of `1` is the element is checked and the value of `0` if unchecked.

I've been trying things like

```
If (document.getElementById("a1").checked)
If (document.getElementById("a1").checked==true)
If (document.getElementById("a1").checked.AsBool()==true)
If (Request.Form["a1"].checked==true)
```

And other similar permutations of the above, and nothing works. Either I have error messages, or it ignores me.

How do you this?

Clarification: the first 3 lines above are in a inside `<script> </script>` tags inside the Razor code.
Ultimately, I need to `UPDATE` a record in a table with this.

Comment: This is confusing. Is this JavaScript or C# code? Do you want to set this variable in C# or in JavaScript?

Comment: Just clarified in post. However the `Request.Form` part is in Razor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer was simple:

```
var a1=(Request.Form["a1"]=="on") ? 1 : 0;
```

The value I was looking for is a string, without any `.checked` or anything like that.
And then I just do a conditional assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean in JavaScript - You need to set the 'id' attribute if you wish to use `getElementById`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a1" id="a1">
```

Comment: Sorry, see clarification inpost. Anyhow, this works when I first load the page with the DB data: `document.getElementById("a1").checked = Boolean(@selectData.active1);`